# Finding string length and append with multiple column in dictionary format from csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe - [image]

Basically -I want to append house and district column

- Then find the string length for both columns; in this case House 263 --> (0, 8), dhaka (10,14), area(16,21)
- also, attach their associated labels (label1 column and label2, label3)
- doing it for all the row
  My expected output- `[('House 263 dhaka', {'entities': [[(0, 8)], 'holding_number'], [(10,14), 'district'], [(16,21), 'area']})`

My code-

```
TRAIN_DATA= [(k, {'entities': [[0, len(k.rpartition(' ')[0]) - 1, v['label1']], [k.rfind(' ') + 1, len(k) - 1, v['label2']], [k.rfind(' ') + 1, len(k) - 1, v['label3']]]}) for k, v in df.set_index(['house', 'district', 'area']).set_axis(df[['house', 'district', 'area']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)).to_dict('index').items()]
print(TRAIN_DATA)
```

I am unable to find the length of the strings under the area column. How can I find it? Also, how to do it if I have another 6/7 column like this? Can anyone please explain?

input dataframe-
{'house': {0: 'House 263', 1: 'House 31', 2: 'House 193/A'}, 'label1': {0: 'holding_number', 1: 'holding_number', 2: 'holding_number'}, 'district': {0: 'dhaka', 1: 'comilla', 2: 'chittagong'}, 'label2': {0: 'district', 1: 'district', 2: 'district'}, 'area': {0: 'mirpur', 1: 'badda', 2: 'dohs'}, 'label3': {0: 'area', 1: 'area', 2: 'area'}}

Comment: can you provide the input dataframe as text? (use `df.to_dict()` and paste it in your answer)

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following custom function:

```
import numpy as np
def get_lengths(s):
    cols = s.index[::2]
    #labels = s.index[1::2]
    l = list(np.cumsum(list(map(len, s[cols]))))
    l = list(zip([0]+l[:-1], l))
    
    return (' '.join(s[cols]), {'entities': [list(zip(l, cols))]})

df.apply(get_lengths, axis=1)
```

example output of first row:

```
('House 263 dhaka mirpur',
 {'entities': [[((0, 9), 'house'),
    ((9, 14), 'district'),
    ((14, 20), 'area')]]})
```

Comment: Can you please explain if I have another column for example "subdistrict" & "label4" then what should I do?

Comment: How can I save it into a json format? I am getting this error TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series

Comment: Use the `.to_json` method of the Series. Did the custom function work?

Comment: I am getting output like this {"0":["House 263 dhaka mirpur",{"entities":[[[[0,9],"label1"],[[9,14],"label2"],[[14,20],"label3"]]]}] Here, label1 should be holding_number, label2 -> district, label3-> area

Comment: This is not what you wrote in your question, then just replace `labels` with `cols` in the code

Comment: Please look into my expected output

Comment: @bellatrix the provided output (`[('House 263 dhaka', {'entities': [[(0, 8)], 'holding_number'], [(10,14), 'district'], [(16,21), 'area']})`) is invalid python and inconsistent anyway as the first tuple is encapsulated in list but not the others

Comment: is it possible to get the value in  [0, 8, 'holding_number'] format? Basically removing  the brackets